# How do I send multilined text in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

This code pastes a 1-lined text when WINKEY + ALT + C is pressed:

```
#!c::
  SendInput, Some random text
Return
```

But I need to past a bigger text, with multiple lines.

Is there some kind of `\n` that I can use? It would be great if I could just have the exact text in the txt file and AHK paste it as-is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couple of ways.

1. You could use a "continuation section" ([explained about a third of the way down here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm))

```php
#!c::
SendInput,
(
blah

    
    
    


blah
)
return
```

2. Or you could use the explicit escaped line feed character `` `n ``:

```php
#!c::
    SendInput, blah`n`n`n`n`n`nblah
return
```

3. Or you could read a text file from disk and write that out (but you may have to change `sendmode` and/or handle characters in the text file that need to be escaped):

```php
#!c::
    FileRead, blah, Path plus Name of Text File
    SendInput, %blah%
return
```